# Can't INSERT INTO after creating MySQL table via PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am fairly new to PDO and MySQL and am running into a weird problem. I've looked in many PDO and MySQL threads but nobody seemed to have this exact problem.

After I create the database, new mysql new user, a table and a few columns, I am unable to use INSERT INTO to populate the database. PDO throws the following Error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cms01db.cms_settings' doesn't exist

If I look in PHPMyAdmin, the database exists, the table and columns exist, collation is correct etc. If I then drop the table in PHPMyAdmin and recreate it manually in there, with exactly the same specs, I can use the very same INSERT INTO script and it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Script to create the Database:

```
// define server and root login
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
// define new user for new database and login password
$newUser = 'admin';
$newPass = 'password';
$dbname = 'cms01db';

// create database
try {
// connect to mysql and login
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername", $username);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// setup command to create database, new user and asign to new database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE `$dbname` CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci;
        CREATE USER '$newUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$newPass';
        GRANT ALL ON `$dbname`.* TO '$newUser'@'localhost';
        FLUSH PRIVILEGES;";
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
echo "Database created successfully<br>";
}
// if shit goes wrong...
catch(PDOException $e)
{
// display error why
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
// terminate db connection
$conn = null;
```

Script to create the table and columns:

```
// login with new user and create database tables & columns
try {
    // connect to mysql and login
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $newUser, $newPass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // sql to create table and columns
    $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cms_setings;
            CREATE TABLE cms_setings (
            measurements VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
            brasizes VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
            shoesizes VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
            )";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "CMS Settings Table created successfully<br>";
}
// if shit goes wrong...
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // display error why
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
// terminate db connection
$conn = null;
```

Script to INSERT INTO:

```
//prepare variables
//measurements: 'm' for metric, 'i' for inches
$measurements_data = 'i';
//brasizes: 'us' for USA/Canada, 'uk' for UK, 'aus' for Australia, 'eu' for Europe, 'bef' for Belgium/Spain/France
$brasizes_data = 'us';
//shoesizes: 'us' for USA/Canada, 'uk' for UK, 'eu' for Europe, 'jap' for Japan
$shoesizes_data = 'us';

// login and insert data into columns
try {
    // connect to mysql and login
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $newUser, $newPass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // sql to create insert data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cms_settings (measurements,brasizes,shoesizes) VALUES (:measurements,:brasizes,:shoesizes)";
    //prepare the statement
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // execute statement
    $stmt->execute(array(':measurements' => $measurements_data,
                    ':brasizes' => $brasizes_data,
                    ':shoesizes' => $shoesizes_data));
    echo "CMS Setting Populated Successfully<br>";
}
// if shit goes wrong...
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // display error why
    echo $sql . "<br>Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
// terminate db connection
$conn = null;
```

Comment: seems like a typo: `cms_setings` instead of `cms_settings`.

Comment: @Leggendario - You beat me to it :D

Comment: Dear lord, now I feel stupid haha. Thank you so much! Works perfectly now ^_^ Incredible how blind you can be to tiny errors like that when staring at the same code for hours and hours...

Comment: Happens to everyone. Happy programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have a misspelling. Change the line

```
        CREATE TABLE cms_setings (
```

to

```
        CREATE TABLE cms_settings (
```

Cheers